# Gmail add-on to pull data from many URLs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, gmail-addons

We are writing a Gmail add-on for synching the user's work schedule into his/her Google calendar. This requires logging into the the employer's workforce management application and fetching data from it. Every different employer is a different customer with a different URL. So, for every customer who wants its employees to be able to use this, we have to add another URL to urlFetchWhitelist and openLinkUrlPrefixes in appsscript.json. We could potentially have hundreds of customers using it. Is there a limit to how many URLs we can put into urlFetchWhitelist and openLinkUrlPrefixes? Or is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Your add-on should be communicating with your server. Your server should be storing the "employerScheduleURI" as a user account property. Then you only whitelist your server, and have your server do the schedule lookup.

Comment: So, you are essentially recommending a proxy server. We may have to go this way, but we were hoping to avoid the overhead of maintaining one.